# Add Comment to User and Post models (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails. I'm building my first app - simple blog. I have User and Post models, where each user can write many posts. Now I want to add Comment model, where each post can have many comments, and also each user can comment on any post created by any other user.
In Comment model I have

```
id \ body \ user_id \ post_id
```

columns. 
Model associations: 
**user.rb**

```
has_many :posts,    dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments
```

**post.rb**

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user
```

**comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

So how do I correctly define create action in CommentsController?
Thank you.

**UPDATE:** 
routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "error"
    end
  end
```

The result is

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: rDjSn1FW3lSBlx9o/pf4yoxlg3s74SziayHdi3WAwMs=
comment: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  body: test
action: create
controller: comments
post_id: '57'
```

As we can see it doesnt send user_id and works only if I delete `validates :user_id, presence: true` string from comment.rb

Any suggestions?

Comment: To start with, you don't really need to associate comments to user directly. You can associate them to user indirectly, through posts. Then, a comment is bound to a @post... So @post.comments.create(comment_params)...

Comment: @RubyRacer So how do I define @post? I tried smth like this `@post = Post.find(params[:id]) @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)` but got error "Couldn't find Post without an ID"

Comment: You should read a bit about routing and nested resources. Do that, play around (since you are learning) and come back here when you can't do it yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your way you should put this:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id #or whatever is you session name
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "error"
  end
end
```

And also you should remove user_id from comment_params as strong parameters .
Hope this will help you .

Answer (score 8):

**Associations**

To give you a definition of what's happening here, you have to remember whenever you create a record, you are basically populating a database. Your associations are defined with [`foreign_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

When you ask how to "add comments to `User` and `Post` model" - the bottom line is you don't; you add a comment to the `Comment` model, and can associate it with a `User` and `Post`:

```
#app/models/comment.rb
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
end
```

This prompts Rails to look for `user_id` and `post_id` in the `Comment` model by default.

This means if you *wanted* to create a comment directly, you can associate it to either of these associations by simply populating the `foreign_keys` as you wish (or use Rails objects to populate them)

So when you want to save a `comment`, you *can* do this:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
Class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def create
       @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
   end

   private

   def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :post_id, :etc)
   end
end
```

Conversely, you can handle it by using standard Rails objects (as the accepted answer has specified)

Answer (score 0):

```
Class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user
  before_action :set_post

  def create
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "error"
    end
  end

  private

    set_post
      @post = User.posts.find(params[:post_id])
    end

   set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   end

   comment_params
     params[:comment].permit()
   end
```

Comment: Code only and "try this" answers are usually discouraged, please add some explanation.

Comment: User has_many posts and Post has-many comments So first of all you don't really need direct association with comments. You can use User has_many :comments, through: :posts. So @post.comments.create(comment_params) will work.

Comment: Thanks. You should add this to your answer - it sounds like useful information. (tip - grave accent " ` " allows you to format individual parts of code)