# Ruby on Rails blog and adding comments to posts and editing and deleting comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a ROR blog and have encountered some issues along the way. I'm currently learning Rails and just feel completely lost with connecting all the pieces. I've been working on my comments section for days and was finally able to create comments on posts, but I can't edit or delete them. I also referenced the SO questions below but am still running into problems.

- [Add Comment to User and Post models (Ruby on Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470896/add-comment-to-user-and-post-models-ruby-on-rails)

Here's my layout:

Comment model params:

body \ user_id \ post_id

Model associations:

```
user.rb

has_many :posts
has_many :comments

post.rb

belongs_to :user
has_many :comments

comment.rb

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  get '/' => 'users#index'

  get '/posts' => 'posts#index'

  post '/posts/create' => 'posts#new'

  post '/posts/edit' => 'posts#edit'

  get '/signin' => 'sessions#new', as: :new_session
  post '/create-session' => 'sessions#create', as: :create_session
  get 'signout' => 'sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_session

  resources :users

  resources :posts
  resources :comments
end
```

comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @comment = Comment.all 
  end

  def new
    user = session[:user_id]
    @comment = Comment.new(post_id: params[:post_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = session[:user_id]
    @postid = params[:id]
    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "comment created."
      redirect_to '/posts'
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating comment."
      redirect_to '/posts'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @comment = Comment.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @comment.update(comment_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Comment updated."
    redirect_to '/posts'
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to '/posts'
  end

  private 

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :user_id, :post_id)
    end
  end
```

Posts show.html.erb page in views/posts folder:

```
<%# show all posts %>

<div id="single-post">
    <h1>User - <%= @post.user.username %></h1>

        <h2>Post -  <%= @post.body %> </h2>

        <%= link_to("Edit Post", edit_post_path(@post)) %>
        </br>
        <%= link_to("Delete Post", @post, method: 'delete') %>
        </br>
        <%= link_to("Add Comment", new_comment_path(post_id: @post.id)) %>
        <%#<%= link_to("Edit Comment", edit_comment_path(post_id: @post.id, comment_id: @comment.id))%>
</div>


    <h3><% @post.comments.reverse.each do |c| %> </h3> 
        <div id="single-comment">
            <h4>Comment</h4>
            <h5>From - <%= c.user.username %></h5>

            <h6><%= c.body %> </h6>

            </br>
            <%= link_to("Edit Comment", edit_comment_path(@post.id)) %>
            </br>
            <%= link_to("Delete Comment", comment_path(@post.id), method: :delete) %>

        </div>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

new.html.erb form in views/comments folder

```
<div id="comment-form">
    <%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_area :body, class: "text-area" %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Again I can add comments to posts. When I hover over the edit tag on the comment I'm seeing this: localhost:3000/comments/72/edit

I see this error when I click on edit

[image: error when trying to edit a comment]

When I hover over the delete button I see this: localhost:3000/comments/72

I see this error when I click on delete

[image: error when trying to delete a comment]

I'm at the point where I'm completely lost and feel I have tried everything possible but nothing seems to work. Please help! Here's the GitHub repo as well: https://github.com/angelr1076/rails-blog

Comment: I took a quick look at your repo, but this didn't seem to include the links for editing comments. Can you check that your latest changes have been pushed.

Comment: Hi Mike. I just pushed my most recent changes to github. Thanks for taking a look at this! https://github.com/angelr1076/rails-blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` is telling you that `@comment` in `<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>` is `nil`. This is because in the `edit` action of your `CommentsController` you are setting `@post` instead of `@comment`.

Change this to be:

```
def edit
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end
```

For deleting a comment, the `Couldn't find Comment without an ID` is telling you that the value you're passing to `find` is `nil`. This is because you're trying to use `params[:comment_id]` instead of `params[:id]`. Change the destroy action to:

```
def destroy
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to '/posts'
end
```

**Update:**

Also as per your code, you should change `edit` and `delete` links to below

```
<%= link_to("Edit Comment", edit_comment_path(c)) %>
<%= link_to("Delete Comment", comment_path(c), method: :delete)
```

You are passing `@post.id` which is an id of post. Instead you should pass id of the comment using the block variable from your `comments.each`, noticing that the `.id` isn't needed here because it can be inferred by Rails.

Comment: Pavan, I did make those changes but I'm still getting the "Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=74" in the stack trace when I click edit or delete.

Comment: @Angel check my updated answer. You  should change the links as well.

Comment: That worked! Amazing how I spent over a day trying to figure this out and you got it in minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @Pavan I wanted to give the OP some explanations of the errors they were seeing so they'd be able to figure out similar problems in the future. As your answer is already accepted I've just edited your answer instead of posting a new one. I hope that's OK. Also, I spotted the OP isn't using nested routes (yet?) so shouldn't be looking up a Post using `params[:post_id]` in the `CommentsController`.